# How do I add spaces to a numeric string every 2 numbers in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net

CONCLUSION: I used a regular expression, which handles both numbers and letters in strings of arbitrary length, in one line of code.

```
       dim rtn as String = Regex.Replace(input, "..", "$& ")
```

I'd like to take *numeric* strings of arbitrary length and insert a space every 2 characters.
So 1233456 becomes 12 33 45 6.

Is there a way I can use format as string or IFormatProvider, like? That would put a limit on how long the string could be though, right? Since I'm casting to a long.

```
        CLng((input)).ToString("## ")
```

EDIT - here's the original question.
I'd like to take strings of arbitrary length and insert a space every 2 characters.
123dssas4rr should become 12 3d ss as 4r r

I was clumsily using

```
    Dim rtn As String = String.Empty

    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each a In input.ToCharArray
        rtn = String.Concat(rtn, a)
        i = i + 1
        If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
            rtn = String.Concat(rtn, " ")
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: A short C# LINQ solution: `new String("123dssas4rr".Select((ch,idx) => (idx + 1) % 2 == 0 ? new [] { ch, ' ' } : new [] { ch }).SelectMany(x => x).ToArray());` (I'm sure you can convert it to VB quite easily).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe not the prettiest but a simple and fast approach is the plain old StringBuilder:

```
Const charNumber = 2
Dim oldString = "123dssas4rr"
Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
For i As Integer = 0 To input.Length - 1
    If i Mod charNumber = 0 Then
        sb.Append(" "c)
    End If
    sb.Append(input(i))
Next
Dim newString = sb.ToString()
```

**Edit**:

Compared the StringBuilder with the Regex approach just for interest:

```
Dim timer As New Stopwatch
Dim regexTime As TimeSpan, stringBuilderTime As TimeSpan
Dim input As String = "123dssas4rr"
Dim result As String

timer.Start()
For i As Int32 = 1 To 10000000
    result = Regex.Replace(input, "..(?=.)", "$& ")
Next
timer.Stop()
regexTime = timer.Elapsed

timer.Restart()
Const charNumber = 2
For i As Int32 = 1 To 10000000
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    For chr As Integer = 0 To input.Length - 1
        If chr Mod charNumber = 0 Then
            sb.Append(" "c)
        End If
        sb.Append(input(chr))
    Next
    result = sb.ToString()
Next
timer.Stop()
stringBuilderTime = timer.Elapsed
```

**Result**:

```
Regex:           00:00:40.8928958
StringBuilder:   00:00:03.3468080
```

StringBuilder is 12 times faster on 10 millionen iterations even though it creates a new StringBuilder object on every iteration. The difference will be the greater, the longer the string is.  Sometimes shorter solutions are not faster, same would apply to a LINQ approach.

Even if this test was not really practically relevant, if i change it to read a string from a file with 500.000 chars(500kb)and iterate 100 times, the result is even better for StringBuilder:

```
Regex:           00:00:15.8409331
StringBuilder:   00:00:00.8262289
```

StringBuilder approach is nearly 20 times faster.

Here is an extension version:

```
Public Module StringExtensions
    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Function InsertStringRepeatedly(ByVal input As String, ByVal separator As String, ByVal length As Int32) As String
        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        For chr As Integer = 0 To input.Length - 1
            If chr Mod length = 0 Then
                sb.Append(separator)
            End If
            sb.Append(input(chr))
        Next
        Return sb.ToString()
    End Function
End Module
```

You can call it in following way:

```
Dim result = input.InsertStringRepeatedly(" ", 2)
```

Comment: Really?  Reading a 500KB string all at once, and doing this to it?  Now you're just making up useless scenarios.  In real world usage, the difference will be minimal.

Comment: This was simply the inverse of the first measurement, few iterations with a large string. Generally there are two options: parformance matters or not. If the latter use whatever approach you like.

Comment: Performance always matters to some degree.  But it never trumps correctness (have you seen the strings you're returning?), and it almost never trumps readability.  In order to know the speed/readability tradeoff, you need to have profiled the *actual code* that you intend to speed up -- not some benchmark -- and seen that the "slow" code is actually taking up an inordinate amount of CPU time.  Benchmarks are useful for identifying a faster approach once you've determined where the slowdown is, not as a general "always use this" sign.

Answer (score 5):

```
string rtn = Regex.Replace(input, "..(?=.)", "$& ");
```

or in VB

```
dim rtn as String = Regex.Replace(input, "..(?=.)", "$& ")
```

You'll need to import `System.Text.RegularExpressions` (or add the namespace name before `Regex`.

If you're willing to `Trim` the string after replacing, then you can get rid of the parentheses (and the stuff inside them) entirely.  You need one or the other, though, so that a string with an even number of chars doesn't have an extra space at the end.

Comment: I know solving a problem with regular expressions creates 2 problems, but...I think this is clearest. "Replace every (2 sequential characters) with ((2 sequential characters) & space)

Comment: Sometimes [the shortest is not the fastest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856149/how-do-i-add-spaces-to-a-numeric-string-every-2-numbers-in-vb-net/7856221#7856221) ;)

Comment: However, (1) it is easier to understand, and (2) no one's going to be doing this 10 million times, and for a few thousand it doesn't matter.

Comment: @cHao: (1) That is a matter of taste, i've always had problems with understanding RegularExpressions. At least it's often indistinguishable what they do on the first sight. Besides you can easily make an extension method from this. (2) That depends on your requirements. Apart from this, a more practically relevant requirement would be to read a string from a file. I've added the measurements to my answer.

Comment: @Tim: (1) Granted, i came from Perl.  Understanding of regexps is kinda required there.  :)  I never found them that hard to get, though.  (2) A more practically relevant requirement would be to read a *line* from a file.  Not a 500KB chunk of chars.  You try doing this on half a meg at once, without regard for newlines, and the StringBuilder method will insert a bunch of spaces that shouldn't be there.  (For reference, though...since `.` doesn't match a newline by default, the regex method should work just fine.)  If you want to test, stick to real-world scenarios -- and *verify the results*.

Comment: Oh, and if you're going to be using the same regex a bunch of times, you should definitely be creating a `Regex` with the pattern (and `RegexOptions.Compiled`), rather than using the static version of `Regex.Replace`.  That doubles the speed in my tests.

Answer (score 2):

I'll give you the algorithm and you code, ok?

1. Get the lenght of the string;
2. Use a for loop through the string
3. In   each loop action, add the current loop char to a new temp string
4. Whenever you get an even value, add a space to your temp string

Voila!

Comment: Yeah, a for loop what what I hoped .NET would let me avoid. :)

Comment: @Thalecress, string is an `IEnumerable<char>`. You can use LINQ and avoid the loop, if it bothers you.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something as simple as this

```
Dim newString AS Char() = oldString.ToCharArray()

For i = 0 To i = oldString.Length - 1
   If i Mod 2 = 0 Then Array.Add(newString, " ")
   Array.Add(newString, oldString(i))

Next

String.Join(newString, "")
```