# Adding space every 2 chars in VB.NET

Tags: string, vb.net, char

Good day, experts. I'm getting 16 chars string value from uart, like this "0000000000001110", then i want to add space every 2 chars: "00 00 00 00 00 00 11 10". What i was thinking it's making for-next loop count every 2 chars in a "data", then add a space between it. But i'm really have no ideas how to accomplish it. That's what i tried so far:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim data As String = "0000000000001110"

For i = 0 To Len(data) Step 2 ' counting every 2 chars
    data = Mid(data, i + 1, 2)  ' assign 2 chars to data 
   ' stucked here
Next i
```

Any input appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add spaces to a numeric string every 2 numbers in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856149/how-do-i-add-spaces-to-a-numeric-string-every-2-numbers-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `StringBuilder` and a backwards loop:

```
Dim data As String = "0000000000001110"
Dim builder As New StringBuilder(data)
Dim startIndex = builder.Length - (builder.Length Mod 2)

For i As int32 = startIndex to 2 Step -2
   builder.Insert(i, " "c)
Next i
data = builder.ToString()
```

The conditional operator(in VB `If`) using the `Mod` is used to find the start index(loooking from the end of the string). Because it will be different if the string has an even/odd number of characters. I use the backwards loop to prevent the problem that inserting characters changes the size of the string/StringBuilder, hence causing wrong indexes in the for-loop.

---

Here is an extension method that encapsulates the complexity and improves reusability:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Imports System.Text

Module StringExtensions
    <Extension()> 
    Public Function InsertEveryNthChar(str As String, inserString As String, nthChar As Int32) As String
        If string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) then Return str

        Dim builder as New StringBuilder(str)
        Dim startIndex = builder.Length - (builder.Length Mod nthChar)

        For i As int32 = startIndex to nthChar Step -nthChar
            builder.Insert(i, inserString)
        Next i

        return builder.ToString()
    End Function
End Module
```

Usage:

```
Dim data = "00000000000011101"
data = data.InsertEveryNthChar("[foo]", 3) ' 000[foo]000[foo]000[foo]000[foo]111[foo]01
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you have already accepted an answer, however you could also do the required task like this.
Make sure to import `System.Text` so you can use the `StringBuilder`
Output : `00 00 00 00 00 00 11 10`

```
Dim data As String = "0000000000001110"
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    Dim addSpace As Boolean = False
    For Each c As Char In data
        If addSpaceThen
            sb.Append(c + " ")
            addSpace = False
        Else
            sb.Append(c)
            addSpace = True
        End If
    Next
    sb.Length = sb.Length - 1 ''Remove last space on string
    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString())
```

Comment: Now every third char ;-)

Comment: Let's save that for another question :) hahah

Answer (score 0):

If you NuGet "System.Interactive" you gt a very neat `Buffer` operator for `IEnumerable(Of T)`. Then this works:

```
Dim data As String = "0000000000001110"
Dim result = String.Join(" ", data.Buffer(2).Select(Function (x) New String(x.ToArray())))
```

If you want to use straight LINQ then this works:

```
Dim result = String.Join(" ", data.Select(Function (x, n) New With { x, n }).GroupBy(Function (x) x.n \ 2, Function (x) x.x).Select(Function (y) New String(y.ToArray())))
```

Answer (score 0):

'This is the easiest and a layman level solution

```
Dim i As Long  
        Dim A, b, C As String  
        A = Mid(mac, i + 1, 2) 'assign the first 2 value to the variable  
        C = A 'transfer it to main section  
        For i = 0 To Len(mac) - 4 Step 2  ' counting every 2 chars and looping should be 4 characters less.  
            b = Mid(mac, i + 3, 2)   ' assign 2 chars to data  
            b = "-" + b'put the dashes in front of every other character  
            C = C + b  
    Next i
```